# Javascript getFullYear function is not working in IE 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

If I do

```
function test()
    {
        var fromDate="01/17/2012";        
        var res= Test1(fromDate);
        return false;             
    }

 function Test1(d1) {


            alert(d1.getFullYear());           

        }
```

It is failing at d1.getFullYear() with the message

**Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'getFullYear'**

What is the problem..please help
Thanks

Comment: fromDate is string not date object to support getFullYear function

Comment: When it's a Date object [it works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/CPM5M/) - if this still fails it means the machine running this code has different regional settings, for example **yyyy-mm-dd** in which case correct string would be `2012-01-17`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you have a string, and treat it likt it was a `Date` object.

Create a `Date` object:

```
var fromDate = new Date(2012, 0, 17);
```

or parse a string:

```
var fromDate = Date.parse('2012-01-17');
```

Comment: still the same problem persists